# Should marriage happen within a year of losing of parent?

Tags: marriage, death

One of my Hindu friend from Maratha community lost his dad in an accident. Right after the last rites his relatives are forcing him to marry within a year or else he'll have to wait for 3 years as a custom, which has no reason except it's a tradition.

He is already not come to terms with the loss, moreover priests who came for rituals also advised to wait for a year since the family observes the sutak for a year. He is confused and all relatives are forcing under the name of tradition.

Please can someone tell me how should he react and what should he do? If at all he is to be married what needs to be done to adhere to simplicity?

Edit 1 : This is a different questions since the person in question has lost the parent and not the relative. In fact hurry for marriage to be done within a year is because of it. Marriage wasn't decided earlier however due to death of a parent a decision to marry that too within a year has been taken.

Comment: Hello. I think it is better to also mention caste/sect so that fellow community members can help with a better answer.

Comment: Generally Destroyer close this question , he did this quite a many times in the past. But this time it seems he missed the chance. :-D.

Comment: @Mr_Green please read question carefully, very first line has answer. Anyway person is Hindu 96k Maratha

Comment: @SwiftPushkar this question is new so I think he must not even bother.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, Paṇḍyā it seems you need understanding to read and digest what is being asked for the reason that you've flagged actually a new question as duplicate. Remove duplicate flag.